# Shiny observeEvent duplicating output

Tags: r, shiny, htmlwidgets

I'm trying to build fullcalendar htmlwidget into my shiny app. However when I try to filter out underlying dataframe(with events) and output the calendar again using observeEvent, then the calendars are stacking up in main panel - [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV73c.jpg) . How I can make old filter version go away and keep just current one?

**server.R**

```
library(fullcalendar)
library(shiny)


server <- function(input, output) {

  df<-data.frame(title = paste("Event", 1:3),
                 start = c("2017-03-01", "2017-11-15", "2017-11-16"),
                 end = c("2017-03-02", "2017-11-17", "2017-11-16"))

  observeEvent(input$typeInput, {
    df$title<-as.character(df$title)
    df<-df[df$title %in% input$typeInput,]
    f<- fullcalendar(data=df)
    output$calendar<-htmlwidgets::shinyRenderWidget(f, fullcalendarOutput,
    env=parent.frame(), quoted = TRUE)

    #output$calendar<-fullcalendar::renderFullcalendar(f)
  })
}
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(fullcalendar)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

   titlePanel("Test"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        radioButtons("typeInput", "Product type",
                     choices = c("Event 3", "Event 2"),
                     selected = "Event 3")),

      mainPanel(
        fullcalendarOutput("calendar")
      )
   )
)
```

EDIT:
I investigated more (web inspect of shiny form) and it seems that with each button change a new child of html widget is created ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU3Ne.jpg)). I thought that with each observed change the widget is recreated (as observe event is re-ran) but it's not true. Is this default behaviour or it could be related also to some .js/.css files? Can I delete the widget and recreate it in observe event part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `reactive` rather than observeEvent. Also you don't need or want to place the assingnment to output variables within an observe or reactive function.

```
library(fullcalendar) 
library(shiny) 
server <- function(input, output) { 
df <- reactive({
  data.frame(title = paste("Event", 1:3), start = c("2017-03-01", "2017-11-15", "2017-11-16"), end = c("2017-03-02", "2017-11-17", "2017-11-16"))
}) 

f <- reactive({
  df <- df()
  df$title<-as.character(df$title) 
  df<-df[df$title %in% input$typeInput,] 
  fullcalendar(data=df)
})
 output$calendar<-htmlwidgets::shinyRenderWidget(f(), fullcalendarOutput, env=parent.frame(), quoted = TRUE) 

output$calendar<-fullcalendar::renderFullcalendar(f()) 
 }
```

Comment: I am writing this from my mobile so i can't test the code right now

Comment: Hi, thanks! However I have tried reactive in same format as you propose but the behaviour is the same.